# Android values not getting inserted in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

[Code link](http://paste.ofcode.org/TuLkx774r9UccAsF5WmGVW)

the details are passed from Login register java class to databasehandler class but values not getting inserted.

log

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table REGISTER has no column named password
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=fun password=mun age=28 username=gun
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table REGISTER has no column named password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO REGISTER(name,password,age,username) VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: It seems your REGISTER table has not fields named password. Can you post your databasehandler code?

Comment: it has i have executed the query correctly

Comment: Databasehandler code already present

Comment: Try to uninstall the app from the device your testing on the run it again

Comment: Shouldn't auto increment be written like this **_AUTOINCREMENT_** instead of this **_AUTO_INCREMENT_** ? @user1440742

Comment: i changed it still giving same error

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks clean there is no mistake in your code but as your log says there is no column exists as password so If you  have edited your create table query then try changing the database version or clear all the data on your phone for ***your app*** and try again

Comment: Are you sure you went to the entire code before saying: `Your code looks clean there is no mistake in your code but.....`